# Why there is an extra "(1 row(s) affected)"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The SSMS shows an extra `(1 row(s) affected)` every time when I execute `insert/update`. For example, execute the following SQL

```
declare @a table (a int)
insert into @a values (1), (2)
update @a set a = 3
```

And the SSMS will display the following message.

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I didn't find any database/server trigger. What could cause the extra `(1 row(s) affected)`?

Comment: Thats odd, i executed script on sql server 2008 r2 i get just two `(2 row(s) affected)` message.

Comment: Yes, it is. And there is no database/server triggers.

Comment: Are you sure? Given the code above SSMS prints (2 row(s) affected) two times.

Comment: @Mithrandir there is an insert and an update.

Comment: @NickW: i know. if i include any kind of execution plan to your code, i get the same output as you, if i don't include any execution plan, then everything is fine and as expected!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That usually means you have the `actual execution plan` option turned on.  The execution plan is sent as an extra rowset, resulting in an extra `(1 row(s) affected)` message.

To disable actual execution plan press Ctrl+M.

Comment: This was the ray of sunshine that parted the clouds after a rainy afternoon of anxiety. I was concerned that there was some strange side effect occurring that my tired eyes couldn't see. It was just the execution plan the whole time. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

this should not happen. try to look into the `actual execution plan`, what is happening there.

Comment: Yes, I started another tab and found there are no extra messages because actual execution plan is not enabled.

Comment: For me it was clustering index update. So one update for index + one actual update.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post as I was getting the same issue but with no execution plan options turned on or triggers of any kind.

I had a very simple piece of code that would not normally have any rows affected  at all:

**DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50) = 'AdventureWorks'**

If was testing some other features of SQL Server with Management Studio v18.10, the code above returned a couple of output rows that were not expected.

**(0 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
Completion time: 2022-01-07T12:04:36.6414442+00:00**

I my case I tracked it down to the connection settings where the **Enable Always Encrypted (column encryption)** option was checked / selected.  I had been testing Always Encrypted, which uses encryption on parameters.

It only appears if the variable is declared and set in the same statement.

Setting the option for **Enable Always Encrypted (column encryption)** to unselected / unchecked fixed the reporting affected rows.

Added to help others who may find this issue.

Fitz