# what is execution plan doing here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update target table from source table. When no new data in source, no update. Before I choose option 'Include Actual Execution Plan ' in SSMS, result shows no row(s) affected which is desirable. After the option is chosen, result always show there is 1 row(s) affected as below which is confusing. But which row is affected since three rows in this case.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

**(0 row(s) affected)**

**(1 row(s) affected)**

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 46 ms,  elapsed time = 38 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

**RESULT: NO ROW WAS UPDATED**

Answer (score 3):

The first row count was the count of the update. As you noticed yourself, the second row count is the actual execution plan. Don't worry. Your data is not being updated. This is a repeat of this question: [Why there is an extra "(1 row(s) affected)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512506/why-there-is-an-extra-1-rows-affected)

Comment: Thanks. I also think this because of execution plan but don't know why. In the old post you mentioned, answer said it is sent as an extra rowset. But why just one row is affected? I think execute excution plan will affect a table somewhere in SQL SERVER and affect one row in that table. If so, I need to check where the table is if want to go deeper

Comment: @FebWind I think the row is in the table that is returned. If you just do a select, it will also say "<n> row(s) affected"