Why the number of affected rows is not what I expect?
I am running the belove code and expecting to see 2 affected rows , but what i see is that 3 rows are affected . HOW ?
I keep the exapmle simple :
I have a table :
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  Column1 VARCHAR(50),
  Column2 INT,
  Column3 INT
);

And a trigger :
ALTER TRIGGER [MyTrigger]
ON [MyTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [MyTable]
    (Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT
        i.Column1,
        i.Column2,
        CASE
            WHEN i.Column3 < 100 THEN 20
            ELSE i.Column3
        END
    FROM inserted i;

END;

Another table :
CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
  Column1 VARCHAR(50),
  Column2 INT,
  Column3 INT,
  ACTION VARCHAR(20)
);

Another trigger :
 ALTER TRIGGER [MyTrigger_2]
    ON [MyTable]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @myAction_Inserted NVARCHAR(50)
    SET     @myAction_Inserted ='INSERTED'
        
         INSERT INTO MyTable2 

(Column1, Column2, Column3,ACTION)
        SELECT
            i.Column1,
            i.Column2,
            i.Column2,
            @myAction_Inserted 
        FROM inserted i;

Now whn I run this :
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
VALUES (''Test1'', 10, 105)';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

It outputs :
(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

Shouldn't be just 2 affetcted rows, one in MyTable an another in MyTable2

side note: Are you really using 2008? it went out of extended support a few years ago, so if you are using it, you really should upgrade to a supported version

@ZoharPeled actually it not a production system ,It's just an experimental one, however i believe the question applies on all the SQL versions .

Does this fix your issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512506/why-there-is-an-extra-1-rows-affected

Why are you using dynamic sql for an insert? That is quite strange.

@Ineffable21 the actual execution plan is off if i turn that on its gonna be 6 affected rows

@SeanLange well I don't usually , due to its risks , this just an example ....

From the code you posted you will never have any data in MyTable2. The trigger inserts into MyTable when you do an insert into MyTable. You can suppress the row count in your trigger with SET NOCOUNT ON

@SeanLange just ran the above example in ssms, it works fine,I get values in both tables !!!

Even when you have an INSTEAD OF trigger, the outer scope will still tell you how many rows were affected by the INSERT, which (inside the TRIGGER) would appear in the inserted pseduo-table.  db<>fiddle You getting 3 rows is expected. One row in the outer scope, and then one row times 2 in the inner scopes: 1 + 1 + 1 = 3.

The OP has 2 triggers, @SeanLange, one INSERTs into the table they INSERTed into (MyTable) and the second to MyTable2.

@Thom I saw that, hence deleted my comment. The solution remains the same, SET NOCOUNT ON
